# Is there any way to change the background of one specific item in a combox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I managed to change the font and the color of items based on a condition, but I can't change the background. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode.aspx

Owner drawn looks as though it should do what you want.